# Vercel “no file or directory” error after successful build

Tags: next.js13, vercel

I have the following code for my /blog page. This code builds both locally and on Vercel. The build also works locally. However it won’t work on Vercel and I would get the error: no such file or directory, scandir '/var/task/articles

My joinPaths function is the following:

```
export const joinPaths = (path: string) => join(process.cwd(), path);
```

I am using this same setup without the searchParams in my /work page and it works perfectly on production.

I am using Next.js app router.

```
export default async function BlogPage({ searchParams }: Props) {
  const directory = joinPaths('articles');
  const filenames = getFilenames(directory);

  const allArticles = await Promise.all(
    filenames.map(async (filename) => {
      const filepath = `${directory}/${filename}`;
      const markdown = readFileSync(filepath, 'utf-8');
      const { frontmatter }: MDXResults<ArticleFrontMatter> = await serialize(
        markdown,
        {
          parseFrontmatter: true,
        }
      );
      return { slug: removeMDXExt(filename), frontMatter: frontmatter };
    })
  ).then((articles) =>
    articles
      .sort(sortArticlesByDate)
      .filter((article) =>
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
          ? article
          : article.frontMatter.status === 'Published' &&
            Date.now() >= new Date(article.frontMatter.published_on).getTime()
      )
  );

  const topics = getUniqueArticleData(allArticles, 'topic');
  const levels = getUniqueArticleData(allArticles, 'level');

  const articlesPerPage = 10;
  const page = searchParams.page || 1;
  const start = (+page - 1) * articlesPerPage;
  const end = start + articlesPerPage;

  const filteredArticles = filterArticles(allArticles, searchParams);
  const articles = filteredArticles.slice(start, end);
  const hasPrev = start > 0;
  const hasNext = end < filteredArticles.length;
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(filteredArticles.length / articlesPerPage);

  console.log(
    `......................Congrats on writing ${allArticles.length} articles!......................`
  );

  return (
    <main>
      <Hero />
      <ArticleCards
        topics={topics}
        levels={levels}
        articles={articles}
        hasPrev={hasPrev}
        hasNext={hasNext}
        totalPages={totalPages}
      />
    </main>
  );
}
```

I tried adding `process.cwd()` to join paths. It works for other routes but not for /blog.

I expect the /blog page to render without the error.